# Getting tangent to point on a function in 2 variables

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

We have a function $h(x, y) = \ln(x^2 - y) + x^2y + 4 \cos(\pi(y - x))$ in two variables.

First we want to show that $h(x, y) = 8$ can be solved for $y$ in point $(2, 3)$. This is an implicit function and want can define it explicitly.

Next, we take that function for $y$ and want to get the tangential line at level 8 in that same point $(2, 3)$.

How to do that?

Comment: At (2,3) ln(1)=0, $x^2y=12$ and $4\cos(\pi(3-2))=-4$ do you get 8 now?

Comment: I do, but now how to solve it for for y if there is no y in the equation? I updated the question.

Comment: I think you lost me. You already found y=3 is the point on the curve, right?

Comment: Do you mean I should only replace all x by 2 and express h(2,y)=8 as a function in terms of y only?

Comment: You want to find dy/dx at the point x=2 and y=3 using implicit differentiation (I think).